# Can someone explain how does this regular expression behave?

Tags: java, regex

```
String [] numbers =s.split("(?<=\\G.{50})");
```

I know what split is, but why do I need `[]`, what do those do? And most importantly, can someone explain `"(?<=\\G.{50})"` thoroughly?

Comment: You should read up about arrays (e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) and regular expressions (e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).

Comment: Read Javadoc for String.split, read about arrays and regular expressions. These are the basics that one should read about first before asking such questions.

Comment: The brackets are part of the type name: `String[]`.  It's legal to insert whitespace like that, or even to put the brackets after the variable's name (`String numbers[]`), but please don't.  The language designers did that for compatibility with C/C++ syntax (which most early Java programmers were expected to be familiar with) and it was a mistake.  If you want to declare a variable as an array of something, please use the standard syntax: `String[]`, `int[]`, `MyAwesomeClass[]`,...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The returned array will contain one String for each result returned by the split function, for any matches returned after separating the input string on the provided regular expression.

This regular expression provided here is making use of zero-width positive lookbehinds, as documented at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/regex/Pattern.html .  It is searching for anything that comes BEFORE the end of the previous match (`\G` - escaped with another `\` as a Java String literal), followed by any 50 characters.

In short - this is just splitting your input of `s` into 50-character chunks.  (Not sure I would have used a Regular Expression for this - but it works...)

Comment: Isn't "\\G" the boundary matcher "The end of the previous match", with the `\\` necessarily escaped to use in a string literal?

Comment: @Andy - Thanks for the catch!   Answer updated to reflect.

Comment: I did read the documentation, but I do not fully understand it at all. I'm still learning Java(kind of a beginner), so I was hoping for an explanation in simple terms. Thanks.